# Escapeing unauthorized enter in folders

Tags: php, html, directory

How to redirect from folder with, say images, if someone type in url for example, www.example.com/images? I realize that i need index.php in that folder, but what to put in it? Something that would say, "sorry, you shouldn't be here, i'll call the cops", and then to redirect to the main page?

Comment: Configure your web server not to list the directory content. What web server are you using?

Comment: Don't redirect. Show an error message (304 Forbidden). Don't respond with "The image page you requested is over here" before giving them something that isn't an images page.

Comment: What happens currently when you request such URL?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put anything just redirect to the root of the web server

```
<?php

  header("Location: /\n\n");
```

Comment: I would like to put some warning and then after a few seconds to redirect.

Comment: why?  no body else does.  And what is calling the cops going to do to some guy in another country.  Absolutely nothing.  Just redirect out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this. '5' is 5 seconds and can be changed to anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.google.com">
<title>Redirect...</title>
</head>
<body>

You are not allowed to access this area. (Will redirect in 5 seconds)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use meta refresh. It screws up back navigation. If a message is important enough to show to a user, then it is important enough to leave on screen until they click through.

Comment: Couldn't this be a good way to place stat tracking code so that dekip could go back a month later and see how many people have tried to access that folder?

Comment: If you want to count hits to a URL, then don't turn off the webserver's access logging. No need to add user hostile interstitial pages.

Comment: I could use a table to count those who try to bypass my pages and go directly to the folder width images and maybe much more. Any better idea?